# lubcurl put data to the end of a string

Tags: c, curl, cloud, libcurl

i will write cycling data to my cloud to display the values in a trend on a html page.

```
$ curl -X PUT  -d '{"x": 10, "y": 20}' https://...firebaseio.com/trend.json
```

My question is what is the best way to do this.
My idea is it to write a string and add the new value behind them.
Or is it better to create a ring buffer with a fix size like this?

```
$ curl -X PUT  -d '{"x.1": 10, "y.1": 20}' https://...firebaseio.com/trend.json
```

What is the best way?

thanks for help and ideas

Comment: so is your question really "how do I transform the first JSON into the second JSON"?

Comment: My favourite is it to write my data in one json and add new data behind them. But i could say if this possible.